# Serilog does not write to CentOS 7

Tags: c#

why Serilog does not write to CentOS 7?

in CentOS 7:
/var/log/test is already owned by apache:myuser
and it had 777 chmod

codes below works properly on Windows..(/var/log/test/mylog.log changed to D:\Log\mylog.log)

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;


            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.File("/var/log/test/mylog.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();

                Log.Error("HELLO WORLD");
        }
```

Comment: try to change like this  ````WriteTo.File(@"var\log\test\mylog.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)````

Comment: still no luck :( .. by the way, I m using ASP .NET Core 2.2

Comment: try this ````.WriteTo
                .File(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "logs/.log"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)````

Comment: ````AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory````. This will point to your Linux deploy folder

Comment: still no luck .. I tried to create /logs folder in /var/www/html/mytest/ and file named mylog.log manually, also had chown apache:myuser to that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it works, when you write to console? If yes, try to use Serilog self logging to diagnose https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics. Otherwise check runtime and nuget dependencies, maybe you miss something, required on Linux

Comment: Hi.. I found it.. this is because I did not use Log.CloseAndFlush();

 await Task.Run(() => { Log.Error(errStr); Log.CloseAndFlush(); });
 
but now, in SelfLog, I got the following:

 Caught exception while emitting to sink Serilog.Sinks.File.RollingFileSink: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'The log file has been disposed.'.

Comment: @Donald You don't need to run `CloseAndFlush` for a non-static logger.